# Auto install FFMPEG on Google Compute Engine (Debian Wheezy 7.8)

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, video, ffmpeg, google-compute-engine

I have a Google Cloud Compute Engine project and want to auto-install FFMPEG on all the instances. I am using the node.js module  https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg to watermark videos uploaded to the server and generate thumbnails. It's working perfectly fine on my local machine that has ffmpeg installed. But how do I install/auto install ffmpeg on all virtual machine instances in the google cloud project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are alternatives that come to mind:

- **Easy** approach if you only want to fix this one thing: run a script to ssh to each instance and install the package using, e.g., `apt-get` or `yum`. Don't forget to supply the `-y` flag to avoid the input prompt. Here's [an example of how you can do this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/19015/67311).

  If you're going to use `gcloud`, you can list all your instances and you can also use [`gcloud compute ssh`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh) to connect to them easily, since GCE uses public keys rather than passwords, which makes it easy to automate.

  If you want to use plain ssh, save a list of all the external IP addresses of your GCE VMs and use [this approach](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/#sshing) to connect to your instances.
- **More complex** but one which also allows future expansion: [use a configuration management system, such as Chef, Ansible, Puppet, Salt or others](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/google-compute-engine-management-puppet-chef-salt-ansible). Ensuring a package being installed on a system is one of their first-class operations that each of them has built-in.

  However, some of them are client-server systems which require that a node has an agent pre-installed, so you're back to square one. Ansible is one that is masterless and thus may be easiest to get started with, but the SSH solution above may be even easier if this is a one-off issue.

Comment: If I opt with the ssh solution for now, will it be too difficult to change to a configuration management system later?

Comment: @DynamoBooster: they're completely different solutions in terms of how you implement them—e.g., each of the systems has their own custom config language, whether YAML-based or Ruby-based or custom—so it's essentially a complete rewrite, but it's incremental, so you can start with a small amount of code to just manage a single package (FFMPEG), and add on as you go. Check out any of their getting started tutorials and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Temporarily I opted for the Easy solution and ssh'd into my instances and used apt-get to install FFMPEG but whenI run the program I get can "ffmpeg" not found error.

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get update` before running `sudo apt-get install -y ffmpeg`? That's to ensure that `apt-get` [updates its cache of package metadata](http://askubuntu.com/questions/222348/what-does-sudo-apt-get-update-do). BTW, if you're automating the installation over SSH, don't forget the `-y` flag to bypass the confirmation prompt.

Comment: Yes I ran the commands exactly like you mentioned and right now I only have one VM Instance running. I still get the same error.

Comment: Could you please clarify _when_ you get the error? While running `apt-get install` or when trying to use `ffmpeg` itself, after successful installation? What's the exact command you are running and what's the exact error message you see?

Comment: When trying to use ffmpeg itself after successful installation. After installing it on the machine, I run ffmpeg and it works fine. But when I spawn it through my Node.Js app's fluent-ffmpeg module it gives me ffmpeg not found error.

Comment: Per the [docs](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg#ffmpeg-and-ffprobe), make sure `ffmpeg` is either in your `PATH` env var or manually set `FFMPEG_PATH` to the full path of the executable and similarly for `FFPROBE_PATH`, which you can find via `which ffmpeg` and `which ffprobe` on the command line. You can also [set paths programmatically from Node](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg#setting-binary-paths-manually). If you are still having issues, please reach out to the folks on that GitHub project and/or start another Stack Overflow question.

Comment: I got the path by whereis ffmpeg and set FFMPEG_PATH to "usr/bin/ffmpeg". I still get the same error.

Comment: @DynamoBooster — Did you add the leading slash to the path? It should be `/usr/bin/ffmpeg` not `usr/bin/ffmpeg`. If that doesn't help, I'm afraid I don't know [`node-fluent-ffmpeg`](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg) well enough to help you further; please talk to the project members and/or start another SO question with exact steps of how to reproduce this error so that others can look into it.

Comment: Yes I had the slash - I just forgot to put it here. Thanks for helping! I just made a new SO question with all the updated information.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use [Startup Scripts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript). I would place this solution in between approaches suggested by @Misha.

Comment: I have a custom Startup Script that installs ffmpeg for me now and I created a managed VM using that but my code still doesn't work. It still gives me the "Cannot Find FFMPEG" error.